# Combine multiple http request or not?

Tags: web, httprequest, backend

Some web design questions.

1. Combine POST with GET?

   When user clicks a button, I need to send one POST to submit a form, then need to GET a json object to replace some DOM fields. Should I combine them into one request so save one round trip time?
2. Multiple GET json request?

   When user clicks a button, I need to GET 3 or 4 json object. Should I send 3 or 4 GET request, or just one and combine the json into one large json at back-end?

So basically, I'm not sure which is heavier: round trip time VS a little complexed back-end and front-end logic.

Any comment is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question right...you have a dependency on your get requests...that is to say the second get depends on the first...if that is the case, obviously you need to take consecutive get operations...however, if that is not the case that is if you know the order of get request and the response won't be affected by local conditions...then i suggest you do post/get operations on server side...trigger the first one an let the server handle the rest and get the result...

of course you would not want users do multiple get requests for one simple operation...

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. The GET is depend on POST, as POST will store some info into database, and GET will read this info from database. Sending two reqeusts or combining them both work logically, why u think sending two reqeusts is better?